# Bypass touch switch on humidifier circuit board

Tags: switches, bypass, touch

i have a simple humidifier that only powers on by a touch sensitive switch.

I need to bypass it because when the power is off after that the device doesnt start automatically.

I tried some things but i only know the basic on circuit boards.

Can you help me please?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: You probably can't. That board most likely uses a microcontroller and that function is controlled by the burnt in program. Bypassing that might also bypass some safety functions. This is a problem with many modern electronic devices such as rice cookers, etc., that can't now be run on time switches, etc.

Comment: Arduino Nano driving a SG-90 servo operating a fabricated faux finger?

Comment: Interesting Faux Finger problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about touch sensitive switch.

Try to solder 2 wires to the switch and connect to an external push-button.

If your device starts with this external switch, then you can add a timer on delay, one second time.

The coil will be connected to the supply voltage, and a normaly closed contact wired in parallel with the touch sensitive switch. That way you will get a pulse whenever the supply is switched on, and the device will start if everything is Ok. Safety will be as if you had pushed the touch sensitive switch by hand.

Comment: I tried it but no luck. When you plug it to the wall the device turns on automatically now but after 2 seconds keeps restarting again and again..